# won't remove spaces in string

Tags: php, html

I'm taking input from textarea form and put it in the long line.
Input is like this:

```
Country: France

City: Paris

Street: Champ
```

Then put it in the long line:

```
$line = $_POST['input'];
```

now, I need to replace spaces and new lines with `<SP> and <BR>`, so I do this:

```
$line = str_replace(" ","&ltSP&gt",$line);
$line = str_replace("\n","&ltBR&gt",$line);
```

but I get this:

```
Country:<SP>France <BR> <BR>City:<SP>Paris <BR> <BR>Street:<SP>Champ
```

Now, if insted of \n I tried this:

```
$line = str_replace("\r","&ltBR&gt",$line);
```

I get similar result. If I do them both i Get similar results which obviously has some spaces in it. So Then I do this:

```
$line = str_replace(" ","",$line);
```

but it stays the same.

My whole code is:

```
 $line = str_replace(" ","&ltSP&gt",$line);
 $line = str_replace("\n","&ltBR&gt",$line);
 $line = str_replace(" ","",$line);
 echo $line;
```

How to remove spaces in this case?

Edit:
I did bin2hex and found out that the space is actually carriage return \r.
So this is the solution:

```
$line = str_replace("\r","",$line);
```

Why did \r behave like space in this case?

Comment: Are you sure your string is one long line, or is it really multiline? You may also be dealing with special whitespace characters, like the non-breaking space.

Comment: try replacing `&nbsp;` with "". i.e. `$line = str_replace("&nbsp;","",$line);`

Comment: Use a hexdump of your string to really find out with which characters you're dealing, see [How can I get a hex dump of a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057572/how-can-i-get-a-hex-dump-of-a-string-in-php)

Comment: Try looking at the source, and make sure it's not showing `&nbsp;` instead of `' '`. If so, do a string replace on `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Post your original `$line` before any replacing is done because it isn't `$line = "some long line"`. You may have the `&nbsp;` character in it which is a space but won't be replaced by replacing `" "`.

Comment: Your code is correct. The problem is in the string. Can you post the actual string being parsed?

Comment: with hexdump I found out which character it is. I edit the question to be more clear and post the answer since i cannot answer. The space was caused by \r. If someone can explain why \r was manifested as space that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the comments will probably suffice but I thought I'd share this snippet, which given your example I had a punt at what you are trying to achieve.

```
<?php

// example string data
$str = "key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3";

// clean string 
$str = str_replace("&nbsp", " ",$str);
$str = str_replace("\n", " ", $str);
$str = str_replace("\r", " ", $str);

$arr = explode(" ", $str);
$out = "<ul>";
$cnt = 1;

foreach($arr as &$val) {
    if ($cnt++ % 2 == 0) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $out = $out . "<li>" . $val . ": " . current($arr) . "</li>";
    }
}

$out = $out . "</ul>";

echo $out;

// output source
// <ul><li>key1: value1</li><li>key2: value2</li><li>key3: value3</li></ul>

?>
```