# Split utf8 string into array of chars

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm trying to split a **utf8** encoded string into an array of chars. The function that I now use used to work, but for some reason it doesn't work anymore. What could be the reason. And better yet, how can I fix it?

This is my string:

> Zelf heb ik maar één vraag: wie ben jij?

This is my function:

```
function utf8Split($str, $len = 1)
{
  $arr = array();
  $strLen = mb_strlen($str);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $strLen; $i++)
  {
    $arr[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $len);
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

This is the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Z
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => f
    [4] =>  
    [5] => h
    [6] => e
    [7] => b
    [8] =>  
    [9] => i
    [10] => k
    [11] =>  
    [12] => m
    [13] => a
    [14] => a
    [15] => r
    [16] =>  
    [17] => e
    [18] => ́
    [19] => e
    [20] => ́
    [21] => n
    [22] =>  
    [23] => v
    [24] => r
    [25] => a
    [26] => a
    [27] => g
    [28] => :
    [29] =>  
    [30] => w
    [31] => i
    [32] => e
    [33] =>  
    [34] => b
    [35] => e
    [36] => n
    [37] =>  
    [38] => j
    [39] => i
    [40] => j
    [41] => ?
)
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What is it doing that it's not supposed to be doing and/or what is it not doing that it's supposed to be doing?

Comment: The éé part isn't splitted as it should

Comment: SOLUTION: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21654160/2377343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the é was not the character I expected. Apparently there is a difference between né and ńe. I got it working by [normalizing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) the string first.

Answer (score 18):

This is the best solution!:

I've found this nice solution in the [PHP manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).

```
preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

It works really fast:

In PHP 5.6.18 it split a 6 MB big text file in a matter of seconds.

Best of all. It doesn't need MultiByte (mb_) support!

Similar answer also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21654160/3341344).

Answer (score 13):

For the `mb_...` functions you should specify the charset encoding.

In your example code these are especially the following two lines:

```
$strLen = mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');
$arr[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $len, 'UTF-8');
```

The full picture:

```
function utf8Split($str, $len = 1)
{
  $arr = array();
  $strLen = mb_strlen($str, 'UTF-8');
  for ($i = 0; $i < $strLen; $i++)
  {
    $arr[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $len, 'UTF-8');
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

Because you're using UTF-8 here. However, if the input is not properly encoded, this won't work "any longer" - just because it has not been designed for something else.

You can alternativly process UTF-8 encoded strings with PCRE regular expressions, for example this will return what you're looking for in less code:

```
$str = 'Zelf heb ik maar één vraag: wie ben jij?';

$chars = preg_split('/(?!^)(?=.)/u', $str);
```

Next to `preg_split` there is also [`mb_split`](http://php.net/mb_split).

Comment: I specify the encoding globally with: mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

Comment: That should set it (but it sets also HTTP input and output encoding), you could analyze the string (e.g. [with a hexdump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057572/how-can-i-get-a-hex-dump-of-a-string-in-php)) and check the string encoding firsthand, I suspect either the encoding setting is not right or the charset encoding of the string is something else than UTF-8.

Comment: The performance is really high in this approach. Please Consider this one which is much faster something like 10000 times better `preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Answer (score 4):

If you not sure about availability of mb_string function library, then use:

Version 1:

```
function utf8_str_split($str='',$len=1){
    preg_match_all("/./u", $str, $arr);
    $arr = array_chunk($arr[0], $len);
    $arr = array_map('implode', $arr);
    return $arr;
}
```

Version 2:

```
function utf8_str_split($str='',$len=1){
    return preg_split('/(?<=\G.{'.$len.'})/u', $str,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

Both functions tested in PHP5

Answer (score 3):

There is a multibyte split function in PHP, [`mb_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php).

Comment: Be certain to set the `mb_regex_encoding()`, too!

Answer (score 0):

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

46 arrays - off 41 arrays

Comment: Could you clarify this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since php 7.4, you can use [`mb_str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php):

```
$arr = mb_str_split($str);
```