# PHP: How to split a UTF-8 string?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, split, preg-split

I have the following code which is not working with UTF-8 characters. How can I fix it?

```
$seed = preg_split('//u', $seed, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$seed = str_split('АБВГДЕЖЗ'); // and any other characters

shuffle($seed); // probably optional since array_is randomized; this may be redundant
$code = '';
foreach (array_rand($seed, 5) as $k) $md5_hash .= $seed[$k];

//We don't need a 32 character long string so we trim it down to 5 
$security_code = $code;
```

I have tried this code:

```
$seed = preg_split('//u', $seed, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

but it is still not working.

Comment: When I enter `PHP str_split UTF-8` into Google, I get a *very* good result on the #1 position.

Comment: @Pekka웃 when I do that now, I get this question

Answer (score 14):

You must create the variable `$seed` and give it a string value before you can use it as the second parameter of `preg_split`:

```
$seed = 'АБВГДЕЖЗ';
$seed = preg_split('//u', $seed, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The output of `print_r($seed)` will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => А
    [1] => Б
    [2] => В
    [3] => Г
    [4] => Д
    [5] => Е
    [6] => Ж
    [7] => З
)
```

I hope the rest of your code will work just fine.

Comment: It is not necessary to pass string into `preg_split` as variable. Function does not require this. It can be string to.

Answer (score 1):

For working with UTF-8 strings use [Multibyte String Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

For your purpose it will be `mb_split`.

**Update**

```
$seed = preg_split('//u', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach (array_rand($seed, 5) as $k) {
    $md5_hash .= $seed[$k];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this not working $seed = mb_split('АБВГДЕЖЗ'); // and any other characters

Comment: Do your have php module extension=php_mbstring.dll enabled?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand how the code with this function has to look.

Comment: Something like this `mb_split("\s", "hello world")`

Comment: In your case it should be mb_split("//", "АБВГДЕЖЗ")

Comment: Now not working (thanks for you help!): `$seed = mb_split('//', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'); // and any other characters shuffle($seed); // probably optional since array_is randomized; this may be redundant $code = ''; foreach (array_rand($seed, 5) as $k) $md5_hash .= $seed[$k]; //We don't need a 32 character long string so we trim it down to 5 $security_code = $code;`

Comment: So I did not get. I helped you or not?

Comment: No :( It is the correct code? i have 
`Warning: array_rand() [function.array-rand]: Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array in C:\AppServ\www\php\total.php on line 7

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\php\total.php on line 7`