# How to split a very long string to multiple string on Android Studio?

Tags: php, android, string, split

Hello i wanna split a very long string ( +10000 character) to multiple String.

I found there is a way with `split()` but i don't have space `" "` to split it.

I have only letter. Can i use a loop to split it?

**For Example:** it 's possible to split the string to multiple strings with 200 character for each one.

Comment: so in php there is a function called `str_split($string,200)`. For UTF-8 look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9438290/4916265

Comment: The string is so long i can't send it to php from my android app. This is the reason why i want to split it to multiple string and send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As solved by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760152/split-string-to-equal-length-substrings-in-java), you can use Regex to achieve your requirement

try

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    "Thequickbrownfoxjumps".split("(?<=\\G.{4})")
));
```

Comment: Please **do not** copy other answers and post them as your own.. At the very least you should have atleast modified the regex to suit the question requirements..

Comment: I couldn't comment because of the Low reputation. I was only posting the link, stack overflow didn't allow me that due to word limit so I pasted the method. And I am clearly mentioning that's not my answer. I know this should have been a comment.

Comment: Sorry I just saw I can comment now, didn't realise that I passed that barrier. Apologies.