# htmlspecialchars() issue with removing the < from </a> in string

Tags: php, html

I am pulling some category names from a table, and I am using htmlspecialchars() to process the string that I get back for the category name. The problem is that one out of hundreds of category names is being echo'd with a bad closing tag. This is a simplified version of the string I am echoing:

```
$value['CATNAME'] = htmlspecialchars($value['CATNAME']);

echo '<a href="somepage.php?parms=foo">'. $value['CATNAME']. '</a>';
```

All of the links are coming out correctly, except the bad one. It is being echo'd as

```
<a href="somepage.php?parms=foo">AR North/a>
```

Without the htmlspecialchars() line commented out, it's output with the correct  closing tag. I looked at the string in the table and there's nothing wrong with it there either. Does this seem like a PHP issue, or should I be looking elsewhere? I am suspecting that maybe there is some javascript messing with the tags, that's where I plan on looking next.

Thanks.

EDIT: Update

More detailed code with what I am trying now:

```
        // Convert characters with special HTML significance
        $value['CATNAME'] = utf8_encode($value['CATNAME']);
        $value['CATNAME'] = htmlspecialchars($value['CATNAME']);
        // Print the list item. If the currently selected Id is equal to the category being listed indicated so by marking it

        if ($selectedCat === $value['CATID'])
            echo '<li id="catSel"><a href="page.php?id=' . $value['parm1'] . '&amp;pl=' . $_SESSION['parm2'] . '">' . $value['CATNAME'] . '</a>';
        else
            echo '<li><a href="page.php?id='. $value['parm1']. '&amp;pl='. $_SESSION['parm2']. '">'. $value['CATNAME']. '</a>';
```

Is still giving me

```
<li><a href="somepage.php?id=185&amp;pl=10">AR North/a></li>
```

But if I change the last line to

```
$value['CATNAME']. '</a>'; to $value['CATNAME']. ' </a>';
```

I get

```
<li><a href="catview.php?id=185&amp;pl=10">AR North </a></li>
```

Comment: Can you show this example (which goes wrong) on [codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com)?

Comment: Could be the javascript, or could be maybe some character encoding problem in particular value of CATNAME. Maybe try htmlspecialchars with 3d parameter to specify encoding?

Comment: what does `var_dump($value['CATNAME']);` give? And also please give the hexdump from that string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057572/how-can-i-get-a-hex-dump-of-a-string-in-php

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Are you aware of the differences for encoding this function has undergone in the past? http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string may have a hidden delete character (ASCII 127) hidden in it. Try to echo out the string in hex to see if u can find something out of the ordinary. Sometimes it's a simple encoding issue and encoding the string as utf-8 before running htmlspecialchars may fix it.