# Php convert html links into text keeping same html structure

Tags: php, html, dom

I am struggling converting html links into text keeping same html structure.

I need to covert this html page part

```
<div>
    <p>text text bla blah</p>
    <p><a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="google">Cool website</a></p>
    <p><a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="google">Cool website</a></p>
</div>
```

into this

```
<div>
    <p>text text bla blah</p>
    <p>Cool website https://google.com</p>
    <p>Cool website https://google.com</p>
</div>
```

I found a nice script [PHP regex: How to convert HTML string with links into plain text that shows URL after text in brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35540793/php-regex-how-to-convert-html-string-with-links-into-plain-text-that-shows-url)
 which collects html links and converts them into plain text and that is part of job.

this is what i have so far:

```
$htmlString = '
<div>
    <p>text text bla blah</p>
    <p><a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="google">Cool website</a></p>
    <p><a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="google">Cool website</a></p>
</div>
';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$links = [];
$linksAsString = '';

foreach ($xpath->query('//a') as $linkElement)
{
    $link = [
        'href' => $linkElement->getAttribute('href'),
        'text' => $linkElement->textContent
    ];
    $links[] = $link;

    $linksAsString .= $link['text'] . " {$link['href']}<br/>";
}
libxml_clear_errors();

echo $linksAsString;
```

current code only outputs converted links:

```
Cool website https://google.com
Cool website https://google.com
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What does your current code output? Can you copy in a sample please?

Comment: Do any of the answers resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str_replace` with the full element.

```
<?php
$htmlString = '
<div>
    <p>text text bla blah</p>
    <p><a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="google">Cool website</a></p>
    <p><a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="google">Cool website</a></p>
</div>
';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a') as $linkElement)
{
    $htmlString = str_replace($dom->saveHTML($linkElement), $linkElement->textContent . ' ' . $linkElement->getAttribute('href'), $htmlString);
}
libxml_clear_errors();

echo $htmlString;
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <p>text text bla blah</p>
    <p>Cool website https://google.com</p>
    <p>Cool website https://google.com</p>
</div>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/830127

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a pain, but using DOM can achieve what your after, you just need to mess around a bit to get the right text in the right space...

```
<?php
$htmlString = '
<div>
    <p>text text bla blah</p>
    <p><a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="google">Cool website</a></p>
    <p><a href="https://google.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="google">Cool website</a></p>
</div>
';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$links = [];
$linksAsString = '';

foreach ($xpath->query('//a') as $linkElement)
{
    $linksAsString = $linkElement->textContent . " ".$linkElement->getAttribute('href');
    $parentNode = $linkElement->parentNode;
    $parentNode->removeChild($linkElement);
    $newText = $dom->createTextNode($linksAsString);
    $parentNode->appendChild($newText);
}
libxml_clear_errors();

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Gives...

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>
    <p>text text bla blah</p>
    <p>Cool website https://google.com</p>
    <p>Cool website https://google.com</p>
</div></body></html>
```