# Extract URL's from a string using PHP

Tags: php, url

How can we use PHP to identify URL's in a string and store them in an array?

Cannot use the `explode` function if the URL contains a comma, it wont give correct results.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11588614/1066234

Comment: `preg_match_all("/\b((https?):\/\/)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/i", $string, $match);` use this one

Answer (score 125, accepted):

REGEX is the answer for your problem. Taking the Answer of Object Manipulator.. all it's missing is to exclude "commas", so you can try  this code that excludes them and gives 3 separated URL's as output:

```
$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match[0]); 
echo "</pre>";
```

and the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://google.com
    [1] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0
    [2] => https://instagram.com/hellow/
)
```

Comment: Maybe you'd want to make it case-insensitive by adding the `i` modifier. ie. `...#i'`

Comment: Just a note, some URLs use commas in their query strings

Comment: @aampudia: Very good approach. But is there a simple way to find urls without protocol, too? Like: "The text you want to filter goes here. www.google.de, www.youtube.com".

Comment: @Marco there is... but it depends on how are the urls going to be received! will the have the protocol but you dont want to capture it?? or the urls wont have the protocol??

Comment: @aampudia: I intend to have a textarea where a visitor can make an input and want to avoid them of making links. I want to remove all urls from this string, even if the visitor doesn't type the protocol. I know that "www" is just a subdomain, but in common this is the most important one. Also it's clear that the visitor just can type google.com and the function will not work, or if he types www(.)google(.)com ...

Comment: Note that url's don't always include `http` or `https`, since they can also begin with only `//`.

Comment: this doesn't return trailing _ from URL. e.g. my url is `https://example.com/path/param_` but in `$match` it returns only `https://example.com/path/param` Any suggestions ?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me  you have to delete the [:punct:] part of the regular expression, that tells it to ingore all punctuation, if you remove that it will take the underscore at the end

Comment: extract urls from webpage using PHP , follow this link please https://infoconic.com/blog/extract-urls-from-webpage-using-php/

Comment: this regex breaks when a url has brackets and apostrophe ' in a url.
Well a good url should be encoded, sometimes we have lots of data to process thats where this solution didnt work.

Answer (score 9):

please try to use below regex

```
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\",]+/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: this query is 'greedy' when the url's are not separated by a comma.

Answer (score 5):

You can try Regex here:

```
$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match[0]); 
echo "</pre>";
```

This gives the following output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => http://google.com
  [1] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/
)
```

Comment: it should have 3 results in the output array. not 2.  `http://google.com` ,`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0` and `https://instagram.com/hellow/`

Comment: [\w\d]+ === [\w]+

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
function getUrls($string)
{
$regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
return ($matches[0]);
}
$urls = getUrls($string);
print_r($urls);
```

or

```
$str = '<a href="http://foobar.com"> | Hello world Im a http://google.fr |     Did you mean:http://google.fr/index.php?id=1&b=6#2310';
$pattern = '`.*?((http|ftp)://[\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]+)[^\w#$&+,\/:;=?@.-]*?`i';
if (preg_match_all($pattern,$str,$matches)) 
{
print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

it will works

Comment: No, still its giving 2 results. there are 3 URL's but only 2 is returned. can u see? `Array ( [0] => http://google.com, [1] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/ )`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390556/extract-url-from-string may be this wil help you

Comment: can u provide a example with that regex?

Comment: no it doesnt work for my string. `$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";`

Answer (score 4):

```
$urlstring = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $urlstring , $result);

print_r($result[0]);
```

Comment: no, it still gives only 2 URL's.  it should give 3 URL's as a result.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#',
$string, $match);

echo "<pre>"; $arr = explode(",", $match[0][1]);
print_r($match[0][0]); print_r($arr); echo "</pre>";
```