# JQUERY : Get all youtube links from string

Tags: jquery, regex, youtube, web

i want to get a youtube links inside string
example

> **"hi how are you check it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_p8ZXIRFJI";**

and then i get the links

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_p8ZXIRFJI

after i get the link, i want to delete that link from string

**For all youtube URLs**

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `regular expression` to extract youtube links from string.

**Regex:** `(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?(?:youtube|youtu)\.(?:be|com)\/[^\s]+`

[**Try Regex demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/tOcxYQ/1)

> **Note:** Youtube link can be this format also https://youtu.be/_3tVL-ZAc4k
>
> **Example string :** *hi how are you check it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_p8ZXIRFJI youtube link can be of this type https://youtu.be/_3tVL-ZAc4k*

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/781478)

```
<?php

$string="hi how are you check it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_p8ZXIRFJI youtube link can be of this type https://youtu.be/_3tVL-ZAc4k";
preg_match_all("/(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?(?:youtube|youtu)\.(?:be|com)\/[^\s]+/", $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_p8ZXIRFJI
            [1] => https://youtu.be/_3tVL-ZAc4k
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @aampudia answer, from [Extract URL's from a string using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36564776/1817690) you can get URL's and parse it like,

```
<?php
    $pattern='#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
    $str="hi how are you check it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_p8ZXIRFJI";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $match);
    // if there are multiple urls then use loop here
    print_r($match[0]);
    echo '<br/>';
    // otherwise just use 
    echo isset($match[0][0]) ? $match[0][0] : 'No url found';
    // and to replace string use
    echo '<br/>';
    echo strpos($match[0][0],'.youtube.') ? str_replace($match[0][0],'',$str) : 'No youtube url'; // let $match[0][0] is defined and not null
?>
```

**[PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hfp4-j1tr)**