# Extract exact URL's from string in php

Tags: php

I need to extract the all url's from the string using php , I refered below url but not getting exact result I want. [Reference url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564293/extract-urls-from-a-string-using-php)
and my string are below,

```
$string = "hi new image one http://xxx/images/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b208754572.jpgand two arehttp://yyy/images/c1f1a611c1147c4054c399c01f8bad76686484492.jpgend";
$regex = '#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches[0]);
```

am getting result are

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://xxx/images/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b208754572.jpgand
)
```

It shows only one result , but in string 2url's are available, is it possible to get below result,

```
Array
    (
        [0] => http://xxx/images/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b208754572.jpg
        [1] => http://yyy/images/c1f1a611c1147c4054c399c01f8bad76686484492.jpg
    )
```

How to remove appending text in front and end of url and filter exact url's from string ? Any help Appreciated

Comment: Are these real url ?

Comment: no, just I replaced host address to xxx and yyy

Comment: But the end of the url, they are what you have as input url ?

Comment: does this is the real string you want to parse? or just an example? the regex pattern is completely correct, the issue is in your string

Comment: also, what about the end of the uri part? are you always matching against an image with the jpg extension?

Comment: Use `@http://[^\s]+.jpg@`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564293/extract-urls-from-a-string-using-php?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract URL's from a string using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564293/extract-urls-from-a-string-using-php)

Comment: @hassan , am not only matching with jpg, maybe its any type of image format

Comment: @RamRaider , am already added reference link , so read my question correctly

Comment: @Mohammad , it may be any image type jpeg, gif or png

Comment: @Thiyagarajan If images url end with `and` & `end` you can use `@http://[^\s]+(?=and|end)@`

Comment: @mohammad , If matching with any string means what we use instead of and|end? am using * but its wrong

Comment: @mohammad using '@http://[^\s]+.(jpg|png|gif|swf|jpeg)@' is resolved m issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in you are matching a link with a [boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) of the http word

```
$regex = '#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
//         ^^ note this
```

omitting the boundary will get the full list of urls in your string

```
$regex = '#https?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#';
```

will output:

```
Array (
    [0] => http://xxx/images/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b208754572.jpgend
    [1] => http://yyy/images/c1f1a611c1147c4054c399c01f8bad76686484492.jpgand
)
```

You **SHOULD** match against some fixed suffix in the end of the url.

I will assume that you want to match against jpg,jpeg,png images , so your pattern may look like:

```
$regex = '#https?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/)\.(jpg|jpeg|png))#';
```

Live example: https://3v4l.org/WACo1

Comment: yeah great and simple one, +1 for answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for loop. 
With the size of the array $matches
And then print the result.

```
<?php
$string = "hi new image one http://xxx/images/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b208754572.jpgand two are http://yyy/images/c1f1a611c1147c4054c399c01f8bad76686484492.jpgend";
$regex = '#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
echo "<pre>";

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($matches);$i++){
    print_r($matches[$i]); 
}
```

Try this, and let me know if it match your needs

Comment: it also give exact result , but hassan  gives simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question

```
    $string = "hi new image one http://xxx/images/c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b208754572.jpg  and two are http://yyy/images/c1f1a611c1147c4054c399c01f8bad76686484492.jpg end";
    $strArray = explode(' ', $string);
    $newString = "";
    $url = array();
    foreach($strArray as $word)
    {
      if (substr($word, 0, 7) == "http://" || substr($word, 0, 8) == "https://")
      {
        $url[] = $word;
      } else {
        if ($newString != '')
          $newString .= ' ';
        $newString .= $word;
      }
    }

     print_r($url);
```