# How to detect link in text by php and send default meta information

Tags: php, url, detection, meta, detect

How to detect link in some text which is included from chat database and detect default meta information and put it to text like on discord.
[ATTACHMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X48yR.png)

CODE

```
<?
session_start();
include('../../php/connect.php');
if(isset($_GET['uid']) && isset($_GET['cid']) && isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        $uid = $_GET['uid'];
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        $check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$uid'");
        $ch = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
        if($ch['username'] == $user) {
            $cid = $_GET['cid'];
            $uq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$cid'");
            $u = mysqli_fetch_array($uq);
            $asd = $u['username']; 
            $photo = $ch['photo'];
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$asd'");
    $q = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $row = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (user1,user2,type) = ('$user','$asd','message') OR (user2,user1,type) = ('$user','$asd','message') ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_object($row)) { $date = date_create($result->sent); $time = date_format($date, 'H:i'); $date = date_format($date, 'd.m.Y'); 
?>
<div class="message" id="message">
    <div class="hr-text">
        <span>
            <? echo $date; ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="avatar" class="avatar-u"><img src="<? if($result->user1 == $asd) { echo '../../img/avatars/'.$q['photo']; } elseif($result->user1 == $user) { echo '../../img/avatars/'.$photo; } ?>">
    </div>
    <span class="username-u">
        <? echo $result->user1; ?>
    </span>
    <span class="time">
        <? echo $time; ?>
    </span>
    <div class="message-content">
        <? echo '<xmp>'.$result->content.'</xmp>'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?      
                    } 
            } else {
                header('location: ../index.php');
            }
    } else {
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }
?>
```

AJAX imports this site to #content-frame every 750ms.
I just want for example paste detected link to `<a>` element and then write some meta information like in ATTACHMENT upper

Comment: Parse the URL and look for meta tags. Thats how facebook is doing it the the ```og:title``` metatag.

Comment: @paskl Yeah I know principe of this but I also want how to detect and select that URL

Comment: Show your code what you've done so far.

Comment: @paskl check edite dcode

Comment: ```$result->content``` is the message you want to check for an URL?

Comment: @paskl all right

Comment: Maybe this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36564776/3020926

Comment: Thanks for help. You can add answer with example and I check it as best answer. @paskl