# What does the number between [ ] mean in a php array after explode?

Tags: php, curl, echo, explode

I am trying to curl a url, then explode page into an array to extract line with a link. I have a sample script, but I don't know what the "135" means. I'm not very good with php. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Sample code:

```
$code = explode(" ",$result);
echo $code[135];
```

Question:
What does the "135" represent in "echo $code[135];"?

Comment: The 136th item in the resulting array. (Why not 135th? Because array indices start with the number 0 and not 1 as first index.)

Comment: If you have a string `$s = 'ab cd ef gh';` and you do `$a = explode(" ", $s);`, then `$a` will be `["ab", "cd", "ef", "gh"]` and therefore `$a[0]` will be `"ab"`, `$a[1]` will be `"cd"` and so on.

Comment: Use this answer to extract URLs from a string, the string in this case being the curled web page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36564776

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets after a variable generally represent the index of an array. In this case, the variable $code is and array. $code[135] is referencing the 135th index of the array. If you want to see the whole array to see what is going on, you can try using the var_dump() method.