Problem useing regular expressions in php for finding all urls in a string
I'm trying to get all urls from this string:
2014 urmymuse Licensed to the public under http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ Verify at http://ccmixter.org/files/urmymuse/47486
I tried with:
$url_str = "";
    $matches = preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#i', $str, $urls);
    if ($matches) {
       foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $urls_str = $urls_str . ' ' . $url[0];
       }
    }

But outcome is: " http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ /"
instead of the awaited two urls.
What I'm doing wrong?

You already got both matches, you're just not processing them correctly. https://3v4l.org/JoLFD

Use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564293/extract-urls-from-a-string-using-php

Does this answer your question? Extract URL's from a string using PHP

The issue with your regex is that it's capturing both the URL and the following slash character.
try to use this:
$matches = preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://\S+#i', $str, $urls);

instead of:
$matches = preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#i', $str, $urls); 

This should correctly extract both URLs from the provided string.
$str = "2014 urmymuse Licensed to the public under http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/ Verify at http://ccmixter.org/files/urmymuse/47486";
$url_str = ""; 
$matches = preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://\S+#i', $str, $urls);
print_r($urls);
if ($matches) { 
    foreach ($urls as $url) { 
        $urls_str = $url_str . ' ' . $url[0]; 
    } 
}

