# Strange Symbols in ID3 Tags

Tags: php, html, mp3, metadata

I'm using a metadata reader in php. It works great, but when I'm using it to put the values that came from the function in INPUT I get strange symbols in the inputbox.

Here is the source code:

```
if($fileStatus == 1){
    include ("include/functions.php");
    $filename=$uploaded;
    $mp3file=new CMP3File;
    $mp3file->getid3($filename);
    $hej = "hejhejhej";
    ?>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="hej" value="<?php echo $hej;?>">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo "$mp3file->title";?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="artist" value="<?php echo "$mp3file->artist";?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="album" value="<?php echo "$mp3file->album";?>"><br>
        <input type="text" name="year" value="<?php echo "$mp3file->year";?>"><br>
        <textarea name="artist"><?php echo "$mp3file->comment";?></textarea><br>
        <input type="text" name="genre" value="<?php echo "Ord($mp3file->genre)";?>"><br>
    </form>
    <?php   
}
```

Source code I get from the browser:

```
<form>
                    <input type="text" name="hej" value="hejhejhej">
                    <input type="text" name="title" value="Selene
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yJjzN.png

Comment: Seems like an encoding problem. Do you use UTF8?

Comment: Check if you are doing it everywhere. Database, database connection, HTTP header, HTML meta encoding...

Comment: Just a wild guess, but it might be ID3v2, and CMP3File might not support that.

Comment: What is `CMP3File`? Where does it come from? Which character encoding is it using? What is `$filename`? If that is a file with ID3 tags, which character encoding is used in the ID3 tag data in *that* file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is "Trim()"

Answer (score 0):

#### Try using HTML Entities.

This might be because of UTF-8 and the browser doesn't support that encoding. May be, PHP's [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) might help you. Replace:

```
<?php echo $hej;?>
```

With:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($hej);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The strange characters you see are because CMP3File uses fread to get bytes from the actual MP3 file (read up on ID3 Tags if you want to know more about this).  If you want to see the actual bytes as a string, use the ord function as such:

```
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($mp3file->title); $i++) {  
        echo ord($mp3file->title[$i]);  
    }  
?>
```

Comment: If you are putting it inside a string, it will not be called. Also, `ord()` will only work on the first character of the string.

Comment: I get this ord($Imagine Dragons���������������)

Comment: i wrote it in this way "echo ord($mp3file->title)" and i get this answer "73"

Comment: Better do a complete hexdump of the string: [How can I get a hex dump of a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4225813/367456)

Comment: I agree with hakre, you might have a corrupt ID3 tag.  Also, try using a different MP3 file and see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: Thanks, "hexdump" worked very good, but i skiped it because trim() fixed the problem. Thanks