# php escaping double quotes

Tags: php, string, escaping, double-quotes

Hi I'm having some difficulty  with escaping double quoutes from a string.

Here's my situation:
I get the the result set from the database then I apply `utf8_encode` to it because there's latin/accented characters and it return the string as it should be exept the double quotes in the begin and end of the string.

If in the DB I have: `"Olá João"` it returns: `Olá João`. The double quotes are ignored

```
$rs   = mysql_fetch_array($query)
$text = utf8_encode($rs['l_reference']);
echo $text;
```

I tried using `addslashes` but without success.

Comment: Please provide a `var_dump` of both the array entry as well as of `$text`. And [a hexdump of both these two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1057572/367456), too. I'm not really sure if these quotes are actually in the database or not I must say.

Comment: Thanks @hakre. Here's a small the initial part of the var_dump of text:  string(705) " O primeiro.... there's the double quotes in the begining. But it doesn't appear in the echo

Answer (score 0):

I think its because "Olá João" is a **multibyte string** and you must use a different workaround for this. Try this one [mb_addslashes](https://gist.github.com/402780)

Comment: Well it is a multibyte string, because it has more than one byte. I never need to use any workarounds for strings with multiple bytes, so makes not really sense to me.

Comment: @hakre thank you, well I know only that is multibyte is Japanese encoding hehe

Comment: It's just a small difference: What you mean is a multi-byte (octet) encoding - but not string. A multi-byte string must not carry data in a multi-byte encoding.

Comment: @hakre thank you for the info, i'm now currently reading about it