# PHP CURL POST - xml response error

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to get a XML response from an external service as shown below. Using php Curl to post info and receiving the response and trying to display in the browser.

However I get the following error:

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: Line Number 1, Column 1:
>   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
>   `^`

can you help me whats the source of this and what does this error imply?

This is my code:

```
<?php
header ("Content-type: text/xml");
//defining $vars here...not shonw for simplicity

$url = 'http://secure.leadexec.net/leadimport.asmx/LeadReceiver';
$myvars = '&VID=' . $lead_id . '&LID=' . '2' . '&AID=' . $lead_id . '&FirstName=' . $fname . '&LastName=' . $lname .
       '&Email=' . $email . '&MoveDate='. $move_date . '&Telephone=' . $phone . '&Address=' . $address . 
       '&Website=' . $website . '&Zip=' . $zipcode . '&ServicesNeeded=' . $services . '&RequestaQuote=' . $requestquote .
       '&NumberofEmployees=' . $no_of_employees . '&CompanyName=' . $company_name;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

foreach($oXML->entry as $oEntry){
    echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
}
if(curl_errno($ch))
print curl_error($ch);
else
print_r($response);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Well, what does your XML contain? What is at line 1 position 1?

Comment: <PostResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.leadproweb.com/">
<isValidPost>false</isValidPost>  
<ResponseType>Data_Errors</ResponseType>
<ResponseDetails>No Data Supplied</ResponseDetails>
<LeadIdentifier>0</LeadIdentifier>
<VendorAccountAssigned>0</VendorAccountAssigned>
<PendingQCReview>false</PendingQCReview>
<Price>0</Price>
<RedirectURL/>
</PostResponse>

Comment: Thats how the response should look like.

Comment: Perhaps your browser (firefox I assume? ) doesn't like that there's no <xml> tag on top.

Comment: Please review your quesiton, I made some edits to it. Also please add the XML you added in a comment into your question instead (use code-formatting please). Also please provide a hex-dump of the first 128 bytes of your XML, see [How can I get a hex dump of a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1057572/367456)