# String Comparison using PHP mysql_* SET NAMES UTF 8 and Mysql Table With utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, unicode-normalization

I have a Mysql table with column *State* - the states are from across Europe - and the table and columns are in `utf8_unicode_ci`.

When I call the database I use

```
mysql_select_db($database_WTF, $WTF);
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * 
     FROM newmeets
     WHERE newmeets.`State` IS NOT NULL 
     AND newmeets.`State` !=  ''
     ORDER BY newmeets.`State` ASC ";
```

I then run it though this simple loop

```
mysql_select_db($database_WTF, $WTF);
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * 
     FROM newmeets
     WHERE newmeets.`State` IS NOT NULL 
     AND newmeets.`State` !=  ''
     ORDER BY newmeets.`State` ASC ";

$LastState = "";
do {
    echo
    var_dump($LastState == $row_Recordset1['State']);
    echo $row_Recordset1['State'];
    $LastState = $row_Recordset1['State'];
    var_dump($LastState == $row_Recordset1['State']);
    echo "<hr>";
} while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
```

The first time when it hits a new value as expected I get:

> boolean false
>   BRUSSELS
>   boolean true

The next time I get:

> boolean true
>   BRUSSELS
>   boolean true

Much as I would expect.

The problem comes when it hits *non latin characters* when each pass produces:

> boolean false
>   Baden-Württember
>   boolean true

When I set them to be equal they are, and then when the next record is pulled (and each record has been entered identically) it fails, this is when I have used the same encoding, I actually need it to recognise they are the same even if the characters are entered differently.

Regardless of what is happening I have tried `utf8_encode` and `Normalizer::normalize` to get a true result from the comparison so I can use this in a control structure (e.g. if you've seen it last time don't print it this time) but it fails.

Comment: Can you include the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE newmeets` in your question?  It may well be that the charsets and collations on the table and columns are bogus.

Comment: [Provide hexdumps of the strings in question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1057572/367456).

Comment: Charles - is this what you meant?    

    -- Table structure for table `newmeets`    
    --    

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newmeets` (    
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,    
    `Country` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,    
    `State` varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,    
    PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)    
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=110 ;

Comment: Thanks Charles, the hex dumps were the way to view it, they showed me that although I was copying the values over they were still not the same ... back to the inputting stage.

Comment: Not sure what I need to do to add kudos to your reputation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a normalization problem in your database. Instead of storing the same state as string over and over again, put all state names into a table of it's own and reference them.

This will also ensure that you do not - e.g. by accident - put binary different but equally looking data into different rows you're not able to properly align later on as you just did.

Alternatively you should query distinct rows and update them, so that you do *at least* have the same binary string data for same-named states. E.g. if Mysql is able to actually align these state strings but PHP - due to it's binary nature of strings - is not.

Comment: Charles - is this what you meant?

-- Table structure for table `newmeets`
  --

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newmeets` (
    `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `Country` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `State` varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=110 ;

Comment: Sorry ignore above I meant to write
     SELECT COUNT(  `State` ) AS  "Count",  `State`     
     GROUP BY  `State`     
     ORDER BY  `State`     
     LIMIT 0 , 30    
     Count    State     
          61    
     Baden-Württember 4    
     Bavaria    2    
     BRUSSELS   17

Comment: As only a small percentage of the table will actually be assigned a state I was hoping to avoid having to store them in separate table and reference them. All the current states have been updated to the exact same value by doing an update on them.