# MySQL: Where condition doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `Traduction` with these two rows :

```
francais     |espagnol         |allemand       |anglais  
-------------+-----------------+---------------+----------------
ORANGE litée |NARANJA ENCAJADA |ORANGEN GELEGT |ORANGE 1 LAYER
ORANGE LITEE |NARANJA ENCAJADA |ORANGEN GELEGT |ORANGE 1 LAYER
```

My query is :

```
SELECT * FROM T_TRADUCTION where francais= 'ORANGE LITEE';
```

This query returns two rows of the table, whereas it should return only the record with `ORANGE LITEE` value (not `ORANGE litée`).

I don't understand why.

Comment: it depends on collation used for field and connection...

Comment: Also, see normalization

Comment: Changed to UTF8 - UTF8_BIN, it worked. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [String Comparison using PHP mysql\_\* SET NAMES UTF 8 and Mysql Table With utf8\_unicode\_ci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068462/string-comparison-using-php-mysql-set-names-utf-8-and-mysql-table-with-utf8-un)

Answer (score 1):

Change your database collate to `latin1_general_cs`

Set your database `DEFAULT CHARACTER` to `latin1`

Now execute your query.

```
SELECT * FROM T_TRADUCTION where francais= 'ORANGE LITEE';
```

Comment: have you tried with set collate in your query itself?

Comment: yes i have tried. but its not working thats why i changed the DB collation

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct it like this :

```
SELECT * FROM T_TRADUCTION where francais='ORANGE litée';
```

Best Regards.

Comment: This returns the two rows too. My database was in latin1, I changed it to UTF8, but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Getting encoding right is tricky, there are too many layers: Browser,
Page,
PHP,
MySQL.

You need to **check** in what encoding the data flow at each layer.

Check HTTP headers, headers.
Check what's really sent in body of the request.
Don't forget that MySQL has encoding almost everywhere:
Database
Tables
Columns
Server as a whole
Client
Make sure that there's the right one everywhere.

From [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)>

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the server. Thus, SET NAMES 'cp1251' tells the server, “future incoming messages from this client are in character set cp1251.” It also specifies the character set that the server should use for sending results back to the client. (For example, it indicates what character set to use for column values if you use a SELECT statement.)