# Simple strtolower not working

Tags: php, buddypress

Im sure this is something obvious i'm missing but I have a string 'GB' that is stored as $str and is then echoed out using strtolower...

```
$str = bp_member_profile_data('field=Country');
echo strtolower($str);
```

I am expecting to see 'gb' (lowercase) but the output is still 'GB' (uppercase)

What could I be doing wrong?

UPDATE
Turns out That the issue lied with bp_member_profile_data, this is a BuddyPress PHP function that automatically echos so it was ignoring the strtolower - Thanks to everybody for helping to narrow it down!

Comment: Please [hexdump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057572/how-can-i-get-a-hex-dump-of-a-string-in-php) the result string.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `mb_strtolower($str)` if the if the input string is in different language that server locale, or if your characters are a little exotic, like `ＧＢ` (I used Full width romaji to write them)

Comment: I have tried to hexdump the string with echo bin2hex($str); but i am getting no output from that

Comment: Going out on a very loose limb here; are you outputting into an HTML element that has `text-transform:uppercase`?

Comment: Also, try: `print_r(array_map('dechex', array_map('ord', str_split($str))));`.

Comment: @MichaelRushton interesting idea. Mario, what does the html code look like?

Comment: That gives me Array (     [0] => 0 )

Comment: and what of `print_r($str);`?

Comment: Not to ask a stupid question, but you did change `$string` to whatever variable you have, right?

Comment: print_r($str); gives me GB

Comment: and what of `echo mb_internal_encoding();`? Sorry to make you test wild things… but the issue is weird.

Comment: mb_internal_encoding gives me GBUTF-8

Comment: You mean `UTF-8`? The GB comes from previous output, right? Just checking.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, yep UTF-8

Comment: Have you tried other encoding in `mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8');`? List of available encoding is here: http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php Maybe using the appropriate encoding will work. I have no other suggestion for you at the moment. Sorry.

Comment: I've figured it out, ill update the main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out buddy press `bp_member_profile_data()` function, it echoes:

```
function bp_member_profile_data( $args = '' ) {
    echo bp_get_member_profile_data( $args );
}
```

You might want to use `bp_get_member_profile_data()`

Answer (score 15):

Try to use:

```
mb_strtolower($str);
```

This may work.

From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtolower.php):

> If the input string is in different language that server locale, then
>   you should use mb_strtolower() function.

The function prototype is:

```
string mb_strtolower ( string $str [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )
```

You could try adding the appropriate encoding.

> The encoding parameter is the character encoding. If it is omitted,
>   the internal character encoding value will be used.

Comment: Wierd. As mario suggested, please hexdump the result string? Perhaps you should specify the character encoding?

Comment: Have you tried it with UTF-8 parameter `mb_strtolower($str, 'UTF-8');` ?

Comment: I get no ouput at all using that MArcel, the plot thickens

Comment: Thank you for marking this post as an answer. But it does not answer the question, does it?