# PHP Parsing SOAP xml string response issue

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm new in SOAP and i'm having an issue in SOAP response.

My response is a `xml` string with value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><InterXXXX><PDFXXXXs><PDFXXXX> <InterlXXXKey>19.1112</InterXXXKey><Data></Data><ResultCode>2500</ResultCode> <ResultMessage>this is a test</ResultMessage> <RecordDateTime>2014-12-18 23:56:06.761</RecordDateTime></PDFXXXX></PDFXXXXs></InterXXXX>
```

When I'm trying to do:

```
$result = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

It doesn't create anything. But if i take the result and manual (copy-paste after `print_r`) create a new value like this

```
$xml2 = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <InterXXXX> <PDFXXXXs> <PDFXXXX> <InterlXXXKey>19.1112</InterXXXKey> <Data></Data> <ResultCode>2500</ResultCode> <ResultMessage>this is a test</ResultMessage> <RecordDateTime>2014-12-18 23:56:06.761</RecordDateTime> </PDFXXXX> </PDFXXXXs> </InterXXXX>';
```

and call

```
$result2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);
```

It doesn't have any problems and create `SimpleXMLElement Object ()` with all tags elements inside.

Why is it happening?

How can I handle my response to take the values in the tags?

Comment: What is the output of: `echo $xml;`?

Comment: Are you trying to use `SoapClient` or `SoapServer`?

Comment: The out of echo $xml is the first xml i given. When im making echo $echo ->output = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><InterXXXX><PDFXXXXs><PDFXXXX> <InterlXXXKey>19.1112</InterXXXKey><Data></Data><ResultCode>2500</ResultCode> <ResultMessage>this is a test</ResultMessage> <RecordDateTime>2014-12-18 23:56:06.761</RecordDateTime></PDFXXXX></PDFXXXXs></InterXXXX>

Comment: And im using SoapClient . Im making new SoapCLient with the wsdl link and i call the function i want. The answer im taking is a string and when echo the output is the $xml i give.

Comment: Please provide a hex-dump of the output string. See here how to create a hexdump: [How can I get a hex dump of a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1057572/367456)