# PHP: fread and the newline character

Tags: php, newline, fread

If I make a simple text file such as the following:

```
first line.
second line.
```

And apply fread in the following way:

```
$fh = fopen("test_file_three.txt",'r') or die("Error attempting to 
open file.");
$first_word = fread($fh,5);
$second_word = fread($fh,6);
$third_word = fread($fh,1);
$fourth_word = fread($fh,3);
echo $first_word;
echo "<br />";
echo $second_word;
echo "<br />";
echo $third_word;
echo "<br />";
echo $fourth_word;
echo "<br />";
```

The echo of the $third_word variable is just, as expected, "blank".
I assume it takes in and stores the new line character. However, if I append the following code:

```
if ($third_word === '\n'){
    echo "Third word is newline character.";
}
else {
    echo "Third word is not newline character.";
}
```

(or, alternatively, == instead of ===)
Then it comes out as false; testing $newline_char = '\n'; in such an if statement, however, works fine. What is happening here?, is a newline character being stored?

Comment: Might not be `\n` might be `\r` or just `\\`. And single quotes represent literal string, might wanna try double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it takes in and stores the new line character.

Your assumption is correct.

Depending on how you created the file it will be `\n` (on Unix, OS X) or `\r\n` (Windows).

Make sure to check your editor's line ending character.

> What is happening here?

Your if evaluates to false because `'\n'` means **literally a backslash and an `n` character**.

Use double quotes to get the newline character: `"\n"` and your if *should* evaluate to `true`.

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/2005038)

---

I really recommend you use a hexdump function, this way you know exactly what's stored inside a string.

[Here's an implementation of a hexdump function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225813/2005038)

Adjusting your code with calls to `hex_dump` instead of `echo`:

```
hex_dump($first_word);
hex_dump($second_word);
hex_dump($third_word);
hex_dump($fourth_word);
```

Gives me the following:

```
 0 : 66 69 72 73 74 [first]
 0 : 20 6c 69 6e 65 2e [ line.]
 0 : 0a [.]
 0 : 73 65 63 [sec]
```

You can see `$third_word` consists of a single byte `0x0a`, which is the binary representation for the newline character (`\n`).

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Comparison Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp)

The `===` operator checks for the **value** and the **type**.

`$x === $y` Returns true if $x is equal to $y, and they are of the same type