# PHP file_get_contents and if returns false

Tags: php, if-statement, file-get-contents

I have a variable that comes from the "file_get_contents()" function. Using this variable with an if function always gives false.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content; // Echos 1
if ($content == "1") {
    // It doesn't matter if I use 1, '1' or "1"
    echo "True";
}
else {
    echo "False"; // Always echos this one.
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($content);`

Comment: Make sure the '1' has no whitespace in it. Try trim($content) == "1"

Comment: If you get the contents of a URL it's highly likely that it includes `<html> <body>` and other tags. They don't appear on screen, but they are still there. As tkausl said, var_dump. Or try `if(trim(strip_tags($content)) ==1)` this will remove html tags and extra white spaces.

Comment: Most probably `$content` is "1\n" (`1` followed by a newline character).

Comment: Also, make sure file_get_contents fetches from url successfully. It returns FALSE if it fails to.

Comment: @Karlo OP says the echo returns `1`. That means file_get_contents does not fail.

Comment: @Andreas I thought maybe he means it 'should' echo 1, therefore another possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison fails because `$content` isn't what you think it is.

Most likely there are `<html>` tags or whitespace characters (like `\n`).

Make a hexdump of your content to see exactly what you are getting back from `file_get_contents`.

[Hex dump function implemented in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225813/2005038).

Example:

```php
$content = file_get_contents($url);

hex_dump($content);
```

Once you know what's inside `$content` you can filter it accordingly (`strip_tags` and `trim` were mentioned in the comments.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be better catch false in case failure (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if ($content === false) {
    echo "False"; // or throw exception
}

echo "True";
```